# Install Ubuntu from iso image on DVD

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a Sony Vaio model PCG-FX501 . I have created several iso images but they can only be written to a DVD as I use Nero. ( because of the size of the file). Non will install and the install hangs without any error messages . The PC originally had XP professional installed. An attempt at changing partitions managed to completely screw up the XP boot but I have managed to reformat the partition to ntfs and the instal of Ubuntu starts but does not complete. Does the install media have to be a CD and if so how can I achieve it please.

Comment: Have you tried a USB flash drive?  You can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), to create.

Comment: Does the computer boot successfully from the DVD? Do you see Ubuntu start up? Technically booting from either a CD or a DVD shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link for direct installation by creating partition
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

or this link if you don't want to create partition(i.e.., directly install and uninstall from windows)
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows